# Angular8 Unitest error: 'Automatic conversion to Blob is not supported for response type.'

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am writing an httpGet call to get images as blob here is the call:

```
      public getImage(link: string): Observable<any> {
    
        return this.http.get<any>(this.createUrl('storage/' + link ), { headers: this.createHeaders(), 
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
      }
```

This is my unittest:

```
  it('should get the images', () => {
    let response = {};
    service.getImage('testImage').subscribe(
      data => {
        expect(data).toEqual(response, 'should return expected data');

        const req = httpMock.expectOne(`https://api/storage/testImage`);
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
        req.flush(response);
     
      });     
  });
```

When I write the test like above I get the error: "Expected no open requests, found 1:"

If I put this code:

const req = httpMock.expectOne(`https://api/storage/testImage`);
expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
req.flush(response);

outside of the subscription I get the error : "Automatic conversion to Blob is not supported for response type."

Does someone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

I changed the response to blob type:

```
 let response = new Blob();
```

and it works like a charm